# Why is brain.getObject() raising Unauthorized?

Tags: plone, zope

I thought it was supposed to return None.

But it seems to be raising Unauthorized breaking the following idiomatic usage:

```
results = [x.getObject() for x in catalog(...) if x.getObject() ]
```

Is this a recent change?

Comment: See https://mail.zope.org/pipermail/zope-dev/2005-March/024499.html

Comment: @DanD. Is there an index that will automatically ensure that I will get only visible objects? Will make my life a lot easier.

Comment: Calling `catalog(...)` should take care of security, as the CMFPlone Catalog Tool always add the `allowedRolesAndUsers` index to search. See https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/e1eac89e1771a4e2b47f1d4c1bf3f5bb65b60e2e/Products/CMFPlone/CatalogTool.py#L309

Comment: @keul... That is how I am calling it and it still gives me Unauthorized when I call getObject

Comment: @sureshvv Weird. So tell us from *where* you are calling this code. From a BrowserView? A method somewhere?

Comment: @keul.. From a browser view with "zope2.View" permission.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, this also happens if parent of the object is not accessible. since getObject of the CatalogTool does a restrictedTraverse.

Comment: @Mathias... That makes sense.. So the object has the right `allowedRolesAndUsers` but a parent object is not accessible

Comment: Well, that's what I assume, yes. Even if the docstring of getObject in CatalogBrains.py says something different. Finally it does a restrictedTraverse.

Comment: Have you included bypassing expiration-date and, in case you're site is multilingual, also include all other languages than the one set on performing the code? Another source can be broken-objs which are still catalogued and/or referenced of the current obj. You can check it with a little helper-snippet I just recently had to stomp together: https://github.com/ida/skriptz/blob/master/py/plone/find_catalogued_broken_objs.py

Comment: To get only visible objs, include the wf-state(s) in the search-query.

Comment: getObject actually does an unrestrictedTraverse to its parent, and from there a restrictedTraverse to the item. So it should work. You can also try brain._unrestrictedGetObject(). It may not be safe, but it may be helpful to see if that at least works.